# I want to apply conditional formatting on cell based on date and then want to sum the values

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

[image]I want that value of cell changes with specific date and then want to add up those values to calculate month to date value.

Ex - Like if `A1 = 26.05.2018` and `B1 = 10`

Then I want to apply conditional formatting in `E1` such that if `E1 = A1` then `E2` should be equal to `B1` and so on with other dates till `31.05.2018`.

Then I want to sum the value of `E2:J2` for all the values of `B1`.

Comment: can you provide your sheet?

Comment: (1) Please write your explanatory text so it matches your example data.  The top left cell in your image is blank, so you are not showing us cell `A1`.  And I don’t see `26.05.2018` anywhere in the image.  In fact, it’s hard to see how your image relates to your question at all.  (2) If you want to change the value(s) of cell(s), that isn’t conditional formatting.  Formatting is things like color, font size, displaying `0.42` as `0.4200` or `42%`, whether dates are shown as ```26.05.2018``` or ```26-May-2018```, etc.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) What do you mean by “and so on”?  (4) What do you mean by “for all the values of `B1`”?  … … … … … … … … …  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … Also, [we prefer that you not post screenshots of spreadsheets.](//unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/23408) Post a textual representation of your data, as was done [here](//superuser.com/q/889201/150988) and [here](//superuser.com/q/892744/150988); use the [Format Text as Table](https://senseful.github.io/text-table) or the [Plain Text Tables generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) site if you want. Include the output data you expect from your input data (clearly identifying which is which) and give a clearer description of the computation you want Excel to do.

Comment: You're asking about accomplishing several different things, but they appear to be separate things.  A spreadsheet can include lots of different stuff, you just implement each piece where you need it.  If you want conditional formatting, set up conditional formatting.  If you want to sum value, sum values.  One doesn't affect the other.  It isn't clear what issue is hanging you up.

Answer (score -1):

> **Ex - Like if A1 = 26.05.2018 and B1 = 10**
>
> **Then I want to apply conditional formatting in E1 such that if E1 = A1**
>   **then E2 should be equal to B1**

exactly what you wanted:

**E1:** **`=A1=E1`** (conditional formating - color green if true)

**E1:** **`=A1<>E1`** (conditional formating - color red if false)

**E2:** **`=IF(COUNTIF({A1;E1}={A1;E1};A1=E1);B1;"not equal")`**

**J5:** **`=IF(COUNTIFS(B1;">0";E2;">0"); (SUM(E2:J2); ("no sum"))`**

[image]
[image]